# Indentation affecting program in Sage

Tags: python, sage

```
k=10
l=1
o=2
F=IntegerModRing(k)
R.<t>=F[]
K.<x>=R.quotient(t^o-1)
poly=((x+l)^k)-(x^k)-l
m=poly.list()
if(m!=0):

     print k
```

This gives output 10 as it should

```
k=10
o=2
l=1        
F=IntegerModRing(k)
R.<t>=F[]
K.<x>=R.quotient(t^o-1)
poly=((x+l)^k)-(x^k)-l
m=poly.list()
        if(m!=0):
            print k
```

And this gives no output at all.
Don't know what the problem is.Almost have no experience in python which might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The 'if' statement should not be indented. It won't run in the second example. In Python, there are strict rules in indentation. You can only indent if a new code block is started. The statement before the 'if' statement needs to be a loop statement, a conditional statement, or a function/class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's your problem.  Sage is basically Python when it comes to syntax (some extra goodies).  In Python, the syntax *is* space and indentation.  You only indent after colons (for things like loops, conditionals, definitions).  Some good places to start learning basic Python are

- [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net) (somewhat old)
- [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/)
- [Sage for undergraduates](http://www.gregorybard.com/Sage.html)